# REACT JS Error: 501 Not implemented issue while uploading csv file

Tags: reactjs, csv, file-upload

I am facing these error:

POST http://localhost:4000/api/v1/upload/csv-order-upload/single net::ERR_ABORTED 501 (Not Implemented)

### I am using these Code:

let headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;'};

```
headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer $(token)`;
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append(
  "csv",
  this.state.selectedFile,
  this.state.selectedFile.name
);

const parameters = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: headers,
  
  body: formData,
};
fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/upload/csv-order-upload/single',
parameters)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("reactNativeDemo", "response get details:" + response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("axios error:", error);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In backend  have added 'application/vnd.ms-excel' to mimetype

In react frontend, deleted content-type before calling the API

Added the following code:

delete headers["Content-Type"];
parameters = {
method: "POST",
headers: headers,
body: values,
};